# Does C# need the .NET framework to run if we use NGen.exe to compile it to native code?

Tags: c#, c++, .net

I know C++ code runs on local machine directly. I also know that we can compile c# code into native code using NGen.exe. My question is

If we use Native code generator NGen.exe to compile c# code into native code, do we still need  the .NET framework to run it?

Comment: Side note: NGen does not produce native DLL/EXE (unlike compiling C++), it pre-JITs all methods.

Answer (score 6):

In fact, if you compile your C++ code into a Windows executable you still need Win32 dlls and other stuffs. Your program cannot run on a CPU that does not have anything besides your program.

The same story for C#. If you compile C# to native code, you do not need the JIT compiler, that is part of .NET runtime. But you still need all other parts of .NET runtime.

For example, the .NET framework with all its classes is not linked into your program. If they would put all required .NET classes into your binary, a simple `Hello world` app would become huge.

Comment: It's not quite true about C++, it's quite possible to link libraries statically, and then they do not require supporting DLL's, but most people don't do that because it makes the exe's much larger.

Comment: @MystereMan No it is not true, you may link C runtime statically, but that runtime still built on top of OS services that reside on DLL or something like that and you can't link it statically, So it is true that you can't compile a C++ code on windows and run it without Win32 DLLs like Kernel32, ...

Comment: @BigBoss - Don't be ridiculous.  The OS itself needs those DLL's.  It would be impossible to run the app without the OS.

Comment: @MystereMan @KirillKobelev say `you can't compile a C++ on Windows and expect it to run without Win32 DLLs` and you say `It's not quite true about C++`. Any CRT implementation depend on its underlying OS and if you link with CRT statically it never mean that you can run it on a standalone CPU without any help from that OS

Answer (score 1):

You can use mono to build a C# app that has everything pre-compiled with statically linked framework libraries and does not need a separate runtime.

I wouldn't recommend it, though. Not everything is available for static linking, and one of the things about using a JITter is that it makes your code *faster* on average across all your deployments, as you can now take better advantage of machine-specific optimizations. It's also not something that even mono is set up to do out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **you need the framework** because the libraries your app use come from the framework.

When you use NGen not just your code is compiled on native code, chunks of framework code are 'nativized' too, just the right parts your apps use.

All this doesn't change your assembly (exe or dll) phisical bytes, this compile the IL to native and store this native bytes in compiled assembly cache.

References in compiled assembly cache still needing some framework components, specially to framework core wich is native code from the beggining.